# How to read data from Google spreadsheet in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, google-sheets, xamarin.forms, google-api, cross-platform

I am searching for a way to read/write data from `Google Sheets` directly. Does anyone have an idea how to do that in **Xamarin.Forms**?

Keep in your mind access `Google sheets` from Windows Form working fine with me using `Install-Package Google.Apis.Sheets.v4` Package.

I Used the following link:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: It's not "Read", but I wrote an article on how to "Write" to google sheets so you can use it as a way to take feedback from users, and it also has a video https://medium.com/the-kickstarter/storedataingooglesheetsusingxamarin-ed8ba5c4b1bc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following Solution and it is working fine for me:

You Need to use **JSON** result from Google sheet, try to use the following steps:

1-Publish a google sheet to get  an **API** link that returns **JSON**, like the following Sheet:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1opP1t_E9xfuLXBkhuyzo5j9k_xBNDx0XKb31JwLP1MM/1/public/values?alt=json

2-You need to generate **C#** Classes from **JSON**, maybe you are able to use 
http://json2csharp.com To get the **C#** Classes and the  `RootObject`.

3- Add The following Code:

```
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   string URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1opP1t_E9xfuLXBkhuyzo5j9k_xBNDx0XKb31JwLP1MM/1/public/values?alt=json";
   var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format(url));
   string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

From the `root` object, you will be able to access any cell value on the Google sheet.

Comment: can you tell me how can i write json data into spreadsheet ..?? same for Xamarin.forms

Answer (score 3):

Reading & writing data on spread sheet is not an easy thing. I would suggest you go with `WebView` that might solve you issues. Here you might found some clue to do so

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-net-core.html

& here on Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 API's are

https://github.com/xamarin/google-apis

& Spreadsheets with C#

[Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725627/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-sharp-using-google-data-api)

Comment: i am searching away to apply it on Xamarin.forms ?

Comment: I got your point. There no official support for writing data until you get official sdk's.

Comment: @Arvindarja's   ould you please update the answer once official support occurred

Comment: @MikeDarwish- I have already read that when you have posted. Definitely It going to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that it really isn't a good idea to use Google Sheets as your online database, there are many better alternatives, if you want to access it from a Xamarin Forms app you can do it using the Sheets API

[Sheets API documentation here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/)

Comment: I updated the question. . Actually my data for my project  is only one table and 2 columns? is this good idea for my case and why?

Comment: That is a separate question, but things to think about are what happens when many people are trying to update it. What about locking? There are other alternatives like some of the Azure offerings like CosmoDb.

Comment: Good I will check it .. but my data is on- demand . In my case I need to check the quantity of items on warhorse.  So is this case able to implement using Google sheet and everyday I will update the sheet.

Comment: Are you able to give us more indo and steps